# Elasticsearch filter result ignoring search keyword

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am getting good result with normal search query.

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

 String keyword = requestBody.getKeyword();

 queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fullText", keyword));

 searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
 searchSourceBuilder.from(requestBody.getPage() - 1);
 searchSourceBuilder.size(BROWSE_PAGE_DATA_LIMIT);

 searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

    try {
        return client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error in ES search");
    }
```

But when I add filtering with it, the result is ignoring my search keyword.

```
queryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("authorId", filter.getAuthorIds()));
```

here I am trying to replace fq of solr. What's wrong at my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from [ES Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match)

> If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or
> filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value
> is 0.

Basically, if there is a filter or/and must clause with-in a bool query then the should clause is ignored until min_should_match is set to a suitable value.

Set minShouldMatch to 1. e.g:

```
queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fullText", keyword)).minimumShouldMatch(1);
```